# Change last 3 frames to still images of 4th frame from end with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame

I'm trying to make a frame editor with ffmpeg with only one funcation.

I want change last 3 frames of input video file to still images from 4th frame from end of file.

Can I handle this with only stream copy? or May I have to use video filters?

Please share your advice.

Comment: You need two videos. Firstly split video (totalframes-lastframes) and lastframes. Apply filter lastframes Finally merge video.